# Is there an easy way to compare scheme:host:port part of URI's to see if they are equal?

Tags: java, uri

If I have two URI's, is there an easier way to compare the base URI rather than having to do the following?

```
URI firstURI = new URI("https://localhost:8000");
URI secondURI = new URI("https://localhost:8000/testing");


if (!firstURI.getHost().equals(secondURI.getHost()) || 
    !firstURI.getScheme().equals(secondURI.getScheme()) || 
    firstURI.getPort() != secondURI.getPort())
{
    //error
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use the `URI`'s `equals` implementation?

Comment: But that would compare the entire URI wouldnt it? Including the "/testing" part

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your requirement. Indeed, that would compare everything.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used the `URI.equals()` method but it doesn't suit at all to your requirement as it relies on really different rules.
Here is an extract of :

> For two URIs to be considered equal requires that either both are
>   opaque or both are hierarchica*. Their schemes must either both be
>   undefined or else be equal without regard to case. Their fragments
>   must either both be undefined or else be equal.

So you don't have really the choice : create a utility method and use it such as :

```
public boolean isURIMatch(URI firstURI, URI secondURI){
    if (!firstURI.getHost().equals(secondURI.getHost()) || 
        !firstURI.getScheme().equals(secondURI.getScheme()) || 
        firstURI.getPort() != secondURI.getPort())      {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it slightly by comparing the values of [getAuthority()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getAuthority--), which returns everything between the scheme and path:

```
if (!firstURI.getAuthority().equals(secondURI.getAuthority()) || 
    !firstURI.getScheme().equals(secondURI.getScheme()))
```

Be aware that the authority also includes the user info (username and password), but few URLs use that anymore, so unless you’re expecting URIs with login information in them, the above comparison should be safe.